# counting number of instances in buffer fails test case

Tags: c

```
/****************** Count ****************************
Count the number of instances of the value in a buffer. 
The data in the buffer range from -127 to +127
Input: size is the number of elements in the buffer.  
       value is the number in the buffer to search for and count
       pt is a pointer to the buffer
Output: number of instances of the value in the buffer
Error conditions: Return 0 if the value is not found or if the buffer is empty.
Test cases
  size value buffer
   5,    3,  {1,2,3,3,4}                  ;count=2
  10,    0,  {-3,-10,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0}     ;count=6
   5,    6,  {-1,2,3,-3,4}                ;count=0
   7,   -8,  {-8,-8,-8,-8,-8,-8,-8}       ;count=7
   0,  -100, {}                           ;count=0
*/
uint32_t Count(uint32_t size, int8_t value, const int8_t *pt){ 
    int32_t i, count, result = 0;
    for(i = 0; count <= size; i++){
        if(value == *pt){
            result++;
        }
        count++;
        pt++;
    }

    return(result);
}
```

My code works for all of the test cases except for number 4, with the buffer filled with seven -8s. When I run the code, my grader says that my result is 5. I've tried parsing through my function by hand and in my head and I can't seem to see why it doesn't return the proper value. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

Taking both helpful comments into mind and changing the `for` loop to

`(i = 0; i < size; i++)`

fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: uninitialized `count`

Comment: I thought my count was initialized in:

`int32_t i, count, result = 0;`

is this not correct?

Comment: `i` and `count` is uninitialized in `int32_t i, count, result = 0;` ,initialize it explicitly. also you dont need `count` variable at all, change condition to `i<size`.

Comment: You have `for(i = 0; count <= size; i++){` — you need `for(i = 0; i < size; i++){`, changing the variable and the relational operator.  You could use `count` instead of `i` throughout the loop too, though then you'd delete the `count++` in the loop body.  You only need one of `i` and `count`, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior because the loop uses the wrong index:

- you initialize and increment `i`, but you test `count` that is uninitialized.
- furthermore, the comparison seems incorrect: `count <= size` is likely to be off by one. If `count` was initialized to `0`, the loop would run `size + 1` times and dereference an element beyond the end of the array pointed to by `pt`.

You should simplify the code and use a single index `i` for both the iteration and access to the array:

```
uint32_t Count(uint32_t size, int8_t value, const int8_t *pt) { 
    int32_t i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (pt[i] == value) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You could even simplify the loop by taking advantage of the fact that comparison operators evaluate to `0` or `1` in C, but be aware that this may be less readable for many programmers:

```
uint32_t Count(uint32_t size, int8_t value, const int8_t *pt) { 
    int32_t i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count += (pt[i] == value);
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you insist on using pointers, you can compute the end pointer and use that in the for loop:

```
uint32_t Count(uint32_t size, int8_t value, const int8_t *pt) { 
    int32_t count = 0;
    const int8_t *pt_end;
    for (pt_end = p + size; pt < pt_end; pt++) {
        count += (*pt == value);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note also that the order of arguments is somewhat confusing. It is probably not your decision, but it is more common in C to pass the size of the array just after the pointer and the searched value after this pair. The API would be more intuitive as:

```
uint32_t Count(const int8_t *pt, uint32_t size, int8_t value);
```